# Why are rational numbers $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness, rational-numbers

I want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$is a product of $\sigma$-compacta, but struggling. Is my reasoning correct?

**My thoughts**: I would just show that $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-compact, which should be enough to see that $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ is too.

However, I don´t know how to show that for $\mathbb{Q}$. [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Number_Space_is_Sigma-Compact) says:

> From Rational Numbers are Countably Infinite, $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Hence
> the result from definition of Countable Space is $\sigma$-Compact.

Could anybody clarify this? Thank you.

---

**Definition 1:**  The space $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ is defined as a set of all rational sequences endowed with the standard product topology.

**Definition 2:** A topological space is said to be $\sigma$-compact if it is the union of countably many compact subspaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the fact that $\Bbb Q=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}\{q\}$. And also the fact that each singleton is compact.